# How to change phpldapadmin default port?

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, phpldapadmin

[I am installing phpldapadmin in CentOS 6.5](http://blog.zwiegnet.com/linux-server/install-and-configure-phpldapadmin-on-centos-6/),the login address is:

```
http://localhost/phpldapadmin
```

The problem is the 80 port have been used by another program.So I need to modify the port,but how to? I have aready search Google,but get nothing. The result maybe:

http://localhost:81/phpldapadmin

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just put config in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpldapadmin.conf` between tags:

`<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:81>
...
</VirtualHost>`

This will cause this config will be available only on `http://localhost:81`